# How to show document in Android with Database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

New to android ,
I am trying one app, there I want to store CLOB in the SQLite Android Database for some ID. So that if somebody click on the id then he/she will be able to open the document related to that id. So I am confuse how to store those documents in database and where can I place it locally to app.
Note : I don't want internet connectivity for the app to download documents from server. It should be locally to app.

Comment: You can store these docs in the `assets` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can store document's information in a table associated with id and in android app after clicking on id you will need to trigger query on database and display the information in an activity or anywhere you want. I hope it will help you.